# Showing the opportunity ID for a new record in standard page layout before record is actually saved

Tags: opportunity, auto-number

Is it possible to obtain the opportunity (or another standard objects) ID value before the record is saved?

Comment: No, the ID is not created until the record is saved.

Comment: If want to get the ID in trigger context.. In after insert you will get the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, any objects Id will not be created until the record is saved.

Answer (score 1):

Id will not be created before the record is saved. You can get the Id of record in the after insert event of trigger. But you can't show it in the layouts before its saved to database.